# Performance of Multi-branch If Statement in SQL (Sql Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, query-performance

I am wondering if it is better to have many stored procedures, or one stored procedure with multiple if-else branches.

I understand that SQL Server will create an execution plan based on the most recent execution of the stored procedure, so the next time the stored procedure is executed, with a different parameter that leads to a different path in the IF statement, then a different execution plan will be compiled and cached.

My supervisor has said that he would like to reduce the number of stored procedures in our enviornment, and has instructed us to use if-else statements to case between various regions that we have data for.
E.g.

```
if(@iso = 'Item1')
begin
    if(@type = 'A')
    begin
    end
    if(@type = 'B')
    begin
    end
    if(@type = 'C')
    begin
    end
end
if(@iso = 'Item2')
begin
    if(@type = 'A')
    begin
    end
    if(@type = 'D')
    begin
    end
end
if(@iso = 'Item3')
begin
    if(@type = 'B')
    begin
    end
    if(@type = 'E')
    begin
    end
end
```

When this stored procedure is executed, it is very likely that different parameters will be submitted each time.  Is this going to cause a lot of Database contention as execution plans are being constantly regenerated?

Comment: What is the purpose of reducing the # of stored procedures?  What do you gain from it?  That's the first thing I would be asking.

Comment: I would not trust people on the internet to tell you which of your two procedures is faster.  Run it both ways with various parameters and measure the performance difference for yourself.

Comment: This sounds very messy, and a potential to break every process that runs through that procedure should you make an error updating it.  There is nothing to gain from doing that but a performance and maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @mikeb We have a ton of stored procedures, so it's mostly to help with maintenance.  If we need to modify a process that exists across region bounds, he feels it will be easier to modify many lines in one stored procedure instead of modifying one line in many stored procedures.

Comment: You say "he feels it will be easier to modify many lines in one stored procedure instead of modifying one line in many stored procedures".  This is bad design all around, IMO, you should write re-usable code.  If you have shared logic, make it one SP that other SP's call. Then you don't have to change multiple things in multiple places or have one monolithic mess to manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would vote for a single stored procedure for each intent or purpose.  In most situations, a stored procedure has, but one purpose.  This makes sense.  Think "separation of concerns" or [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design principles.  It will also be easier to maintain.  It is a lot easier to understand and change a few small stored procedures than one of larger or excessive complexity.

If you do a large stored procedure with multiple parameters as you describe above you will have to take precautions against the problems of parameter sniffing and bad plan caching.  Here is a nice article by Brent Ozar that does a good job of describing the problem and what to do about it.  [What is Parameter Sniffing?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  There is one singular purpose of the stored procedure, to get a credit value.  However, we have 5 different regions and 2-3 different product types for each region, each that can have their own credit value.  The values are stored in different tables in the database as the source data differs between region.  Ideally, we'd have a data warehouse where all the data is scrubbed and normalized, but that is something that will have to wait for the future.

Comment: It sounds like in that situation, I might be inclined to go with a single stored procedure and build the sql dynamically based on the inputs which can be a bit painful.  Perhaps leverage some CTEs or table functions?  I may have to change my vote with the new information.  I might be inclined to agree with your supervisor.  Better to have a single source (sproc) to get the data then to have to your applications decide where to go for the data.  The best approach really depends on your data and your business logic.